# Prevent udev from processing rules for a device

Tags: udev

On Ubuntu 20.04 I modified `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules` as follows, because I don't want udev to touch my raw keyboard device:

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update

ACTION=="remove", GOTO="evdev_end"
KERNEL!="event*", GOTO="evdev_end"

ATTRS{name}=="AT Raw Set 2 keyboard", GOTO="evdev_end"

[...]

LABEL="evdev_end"
```

This works, but I'm concerned about the "do not edit this file" line. I want a cleaner way to do the same thing.  I tried to move this line to a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/01-atkbdraw.rules`, but this results in the following error: `GOTO="evdev_end" has no matching label, ignoring`.

I also tried to use the := operator like this:

```
ATTRS{name}=="AT Raw Set 2 keyboard", RUN:="/bin/true"
```

But this doesn't work, I think it only affects the "RUN" keys and doesn't stop further processing entirely.

I saw that there was a option called last_rule which seems to be exactly what I need, but it got removed in version 147.

Is there a way I can do what I want without editing `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules`?

Answer (score 1):

Copy `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules`. Just keep same filename, it will be overridden. Check `man udev` for folders priority.

That note is in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules`, because files in that folder are part of installed packages and they might get overwritten by updates.

Comment: I appreciate that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`GOTO="evdev_end"` is wrong !! no matches the file name.

Must be `GOTO="atkbdraw_end"` for your file `01-atkbdraw.rules`